# How to create xpi from a batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, zip, rar, xpi

I wanted to automate the process of creating xpi using winrar with pwd being used instead of passing the current dir from outisde.

```
@REM ------- BEGIN xpi.bat ----------------
@setlocal
@echo off
set path="C:\Program Files\WinRAR\";%path%

winrar.exe a -afzip -r -ep1 %PWD%/MYaddon.xpi %PWD%

REM ------- END xpi.bat ------------------
```

**Edit : So here is the final batch:**

```
@REM ------- BEGIN xpi.bat ----------------
@setlocal
@echo off
set path="C:\Program Files\WinRAR\";%path%
erase "%CD%\MyAddon.xpi"
winrar.exe a -afzip -r -ep1 "%CD%\MyAddon.xpi" "%CD%/*"

REM ------- END xpi.bat ------------------
```

Comment: tweak: you may beed to exclude xpi.bat from the final .xpi file so here is a tip change last line to 

winrar.exe a -afzip **-xxpi.bat** -r -ep1 "%CD%\MyAddon.xpi" "%CD%/*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `"%CD%\MYaddon.xpi"`.

- In windows, to retrieve the current directory, the `%CD%` variable is used.
- Windows can handle slashes as directory separator, but not all programs running in windows do, so, it is better to use backslashes.

Comment: The resulting xpi is corrupt

Comment: @adnankamili, If you have your batch in the same folder, exclude it. Change your code as `winrar.exe a -afzip -m5 -ed -pTest -r -ep1 -x"%~nx0" "%CD%\MyAddon.xpi" "%CD%\*"` Anyway, it should be better to have the files required for your addon in a separate folder and then use `winrar.exe a -afzip -m5 -ed -pTest -r -ep1 "%CD%\MyAddon.xpi" "%CD%\addonFolder\*"`

Comment: @adnankamili, i have now readed your parameter list. I think you can not password protect a .xpi file (see [here](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/959622) )